# Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

An error occurred when I tried to put the service `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` as an argument for my listener `UserDeletionListener`.

My service:

```
se.doctrine_listener.user_deletion:
        class: SE\CoreBundle\DoctrineListener\UserDeletionListener
        arguments:
              - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove }
```

My listener:

```
namespace SE\CoreBundle\DoctrineListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use SE\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserDeletionListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
/...
```

Here is the error:

```
Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to inject the entity manager into a doctrine event listener - you can get it in the corresponding callback (`preRemove` in your case) using the LifecycleEventArgs argument.

Comment: For further reading, see [Creating the Listener Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-listener-class), specifically: *In each event, you have access to a LifecycleEventArgs object, which gives you access to both the entity object of the event and the entity manager itself.*

Comment: And the reason for the error is the way the container initializes the entity manager and the listeners.  The manager is dependent on the listeners so making a listener dependent on the manager will cause a circular reference.  Pasting your error message into a browser search bar will give you the same explanation.   And by the way, if you are tempted to access the entity manager in a listener then what you trying to do probably won't work anyways.  Doctrine events are extremely limited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you use EventArgs {lifecycle, preUpdate, etc...], you don't have to pass doctrine.orm.entity_manager anymore :-D You can get it by the method getEntityManager of the eventArgs itself

Answer (score 3):

Add Lazy loading to doctrine Event Listener

*
- { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove, lazy: true }

Comment: nice and easy way ;)